# How to pass an param for WHERE IN query

Tags: postgresql

I have written a function which receive a text array and return a jsonb like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1(name text[]) RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS '
BEGIN
  RETURN
    array_to_json(
      ARRAY (
        SELECT id
        FROM table_1 t
        WHERE t.name IN ($1)
      )
    );
END;
';
```

So is there any way to pass the 'name' param to $1?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved when I replace the `IN($1)` to `= ANY($1)`.